# getting java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors! for jmeter

Tags: jmeter, alpn

I am using jmeter 5.2.1 and I have downloaded the compatible version of ALPN boot and using the http2 view results listener. But still getting below error. Can someone please help.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:138)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:69)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:280)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:140)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:117)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you missed the [important bit of the HTTP2 Plugin installation instructions](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin#step-to-use-http2-sampler):

> 2- On Windows at the start of jmeter.bat add the next line: `set JVM_ARGS= -Xbootclasspath/p:<path.to.jar>;`
>
> On Linux and Mac at the start of jmeter.sh add the next line (see Notes JMeter for macOS section at the bottom as well): `JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath/p:<path.to.jar>"`\
>
> 3- Restart JMeter

For example my Java version is `1.8.0_202` hence I need `alpn-boot-8.1.13.v20181017.jar` and the first 3 lines of my [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/jmeter.bat) file look like:

```
@echo off
set JVM_ARGS= -Xbootclasspath/p:c:\apps\jmeter\lib\alpn-boot-8.1.13.v20181017.jar
rem   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
```

And HTTP2 plugin is fully functional:

[image]

You might also be interested in [HTTP/2 - How to get ready for the future](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http2-how-get-ready-future) article which highlights the main features of the HTTP2 protocol which you should be aware of when it comes to performance testing.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I have added the JVM_ARGS= -Xbootclasspath/p:<path.to.jar>; in my jmeter file. Do I need to add like "set VM_ARGS= -Xbootclasspath/p:<path.to.jar>;" or just "JVM_ARGS= -Xbootclasspath/p:<path.to.jar>;"

Comment: ##   JVM_ARGS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g" jmeter etc.
     JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Users\469956\Desktop\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib\alpn-boot-8.1.13.v20181017.jar;"

Comment: However, I am not seeing the 3 lines what you are seeing in my jmeter.bat cmd line

Comment: I am getting this error now. ava.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:130)
 at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:69)
 at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:280)
 at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:140)
 at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:117)
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)